# About an Integration problem

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Can someone given me a hint on the following problem, many thanks!

Let $F$ be a distribution function, and $d(F)$ the set of all discontinuity points of $F$. Prove that:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}F\,\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}_F=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{t\,\in \,d(F)}[F(t)-F(t-)]^2,$$
where $\mathbb{P}_F$ is the probability measure induced by distribution function $F$ on $\mathbb{R}$.  (Here, $F$ is viewed as a ''random variable'', or a measurable function.)

Comment: Sorry, is $F$ the cumulative distribution or the probability density? I guess I assume it must be the cumulative distribution since that makes the statement true...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $F$ is the cumulative distribution, and $P$ is the probability measure associated with $F$, then $dP = dF(x)$, and then you can apply the fundamental theorem of calculus, where you must first break up the integral across all the intervals where $F$ is discontinuous at the endpoints of those intervals.

Comment: I am sorry for ambiguity. Here $F$ is a cdf. My problem is that where does the number $\frac{1}{2}$ pop out? Could you please give me some logic for this number? Thanks a lot!

Comment: And other question is that how can we show that $d P_F=d F(x)$?

Comment: It is more or less the definition. But I guess, specifically, $F(x) = P_F(-\infty, x) = \int_{-\infty}^x dP_F$, so it must be the antiderivative.

Comment: Sorry, I am afraid this is not the case. By definition, $\mathbb{P}_F$ is the probability measure induced by the measurable function (random variable $F$), that is to say, $\mathbb{P}_F\{(-\infty, s]\}=\mathbb{P}\{w\in X\,|\,F(x(w))\le s\}$, where $(X, \Sigma, \mathbb{P})$ is the original probability space. I think the core here is that we view $F$ as a new random variable defined over $\mathbb{R}$, which is obviously different from the random variable $x$.

Comment: Sorry, I think you are right. Sorry for misleading...

Comment: But what if $d(F)$ has accumulation points?

Comment: Is that possible for $F$ a cumulative distribution function? I don't know.